# Create CommonsChunk - include items from async chunks

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can I create a commons chunk with anything from `node_modules` that's used anywhere, including async chunks (things loaded with `System.import`).

What I have is this

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'all-node',
    filename: 'all-node.js',
    minChunks(module, count) {
        var context = module.context;
        return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
    },
}),
```

this works perfectly, **but** it only includes items from node_modules that are used in my entry chunk. How do I get it to **also** include things from node_modules that are used in any of my code split modules (things loaded from System.import) - ideally without listing them all out, manually, by name?

(this is a simplification of my real use case)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I came across it while trying to resolve the issue I was having. I added deepChildren: true and I saw the results I was looking for.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'NAME_OF_ENTRY_BUNDLE',
    children: true,
    async: 'NEW_COMMON_CHUNK_NAME',
    minChunks(module, count) {
        return count >= 2;
    },
    deepChildren: true
}),
```